# I am getting primevue error with vue jest test

Tags: javascript, vue.js, testing, jestjs, primevue

I am writing a test with Vue jest. But when I say run:test "No PrimeVue Confirmation provided!" It shows that this error is caused by useToast() and useConfirm() services.

```
"transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!primevue/.*)"
    ]
```

I pasted this where I wrote the jest and the final version was as follows.

```
   "jest": {
    "preset": "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.vue$": "vue-jest"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!primevue/.*)"
    ]
  }
```

It continued to give errors in this state.

I also added PrimeVue globally in the .spec.js file I wrote a test for.

```
import PrimeVue from "primevue/config";

  const wrapper = mount(VehicleInfo, {
      global:{
        plugins: [PrimeVue]
      },
      props: { nationCode:1 }
    })
```

error is here:

```
   No PrimeVue Confirmation provided!

      66 |     })
    > 67 |     const confirm = useConfirm()
         |                     ^
      68 |     const toast=useToast()
```

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
import { useConfirm } from 'primevue/useconfirm';
import PrimeVue from 'primevue/config';
import ConfirmationService from 'primevue/confirmationservice';

const wrapper = shallowMount(MyComponent, {
  props: { aProp },
  global: {
    components: { useConfirm },
    plugins: [PrimeVue, ConfirmationService],
  },
});
```

Comment: Also, I think the problem with file formats that required you to add `transformIgnorePatterns` for primevue files has gone away, so you should not need that anymore.